# How much work is required to lift an object (laying horizontally on ground) to vertical position?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, work

Consider we know mass and length of an object. Blue line is initial position and black one is final position of an object.  Confused about Work needed to lift it. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Conservation of Energy principle.

Say your object has length $L$ and mass $m$. Its centre of gravity (CoG) is right in the middle of its length.

That means that the potential energy $U$ for an increase of the CoF in the vertical position by $\Delta h$ increases by:

$$\Delta U=mg\Delta h=mg\frac{L}{2}$$

This also the work done to make this change, so:

$$W=\frac12 mgL$$